# .value no me funciona js

Tags: javascript

Estoy aprendiendo js pero cuando intento obtener el valor de un input con el `.value` me indica que la variable tiene como valor **`any`**, ¿Cuál podría ser el error?

```js
(function() 
{
    var input1=document.getElementById("numero1").value; **//aqui es el problema**
    botonSumar.addEventListener("click",operacionSumar);
    function operacionSumar()
    {   
        alert(input1)
    } 
}
```

```html
<div id="contenedor">
    <input type="number" id="numero1">
    <button id="botons">Sumar</button>
</div>
```

Es el código recortado pero creo que se entiende el problema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Razón del problema principal

De la manera en que comienzas ese fragmento asumimos que function es una [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Glossary/IIFE) por lo cual, se ejecutará inmediatamente cuando sea cargada por el navegador.
Esto conlleva a que en ese momento, al llenarse input1, es muy probable que el valor no esté seteado por el usuario y resulte en que ese valor quede en `undefined`.
Si obtenemos el valor dentro de la operacionSumar() entonces la variable se llenaría cuando se toca el botón sumar, y ahí tendría más sentido

```
function operacionSumar() {
    ...
    let input1=document.getElementById("numero1").value;
    ...
}
```

## Otras consideraciones

Hacer referencia botonSumar si no está instanciado previamente, también puede resultar en error, para lo cual necesitamos conseguir la referencia, en tu caso con:

```
let botonSumar = document.getElementById("botons")
```

Recuerda que los value de un campo input, aunque hayan sido declarados de tipo number, siempre retornan un string, así que es necesario hacer la conversión si deseas sumar

```
let suma = Number(input1) + Number(input2);
```

## Código completo

```js
(function() 
 {
  let botonSumar=document.getElementById("botons")
  botonSumar.addEventListener("click",operacionSumar);
  function operacionSumar()
  {   
    let input1=document.getElementById("numero1").value;
    let input2=document.getElementById("numero2").value;
    let suma = Number(input1) + Number(input2);
    alert(suma);
  } 
})();
```

```html
<div id="contenedor">
  <input type="number" id="numero1">
  +
  <input type="number" id="numero2">
  <button id="botons">Sumar</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tendrías que llamar a la función `operacionSumar()` desde afuera. También, en tu HTML tienes una `id` llamado `botons`, y esto nunca lo estás utilizando, cámbialo por `botonSumar`:

```js
var botonSumar = document.getElementById("botonSumar"); // obtengo al botón.
botonSumar.addEventListener("click", operacionSumar); // y digo que al hacer clic al botón, ejecute la función "operacionSumar".

function operacionSumar() {
  var input1 = document.getElementById("numero1").value; // obtengo al valor del input.
  console.log(input1); // muestro el valor del input en consola.
  alert(input1); // muestro el valor del input en un alert.
}
```

```html
<div id="contenedor">
  <input type="number" id="numero1">
  <button id="botonSumar">Sumar</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que el value del input lo declaras inicialmente antes de llamar a la función operacionSumar, por lo que input1 no tiene valor.
Una solución podría ser definir input1 dentro de la función, entonces al clickearla tomaría el valor y luego lo mostraría en el alert.

```
Ejemplo funcional:
```

```html
      <body>
        <div id="contenedor">
          <input type="number" id="numero1" />
          <button id="botons">Sumar</button>
        </div>
        <script>
          var botonSumar = document.getElementById("botons");
          botonSumar.addEventListener("click", operacionSumar);
          function operacionSumar() {
            var input1 = document.getElementById("numero1").value;
            alert(input1);
          }
        </script>
      </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer-lo de la siguiente manera...

```
      <div id="contenedor">
        <input type="number" id="numero1" value="10" />
        <input id="input1" type="button" value="Sumar" />
      </div>


    <script>
    let suma = document.getElementById("numero1").value; 

        input1.onclick = function operacionSumar() {

            alert(suma);
        }
    </script>
```